# Draw a border line across the entire row where value of G1 > G4:G76

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

I have a dynamic value in G1 (updates every 5 mins).
[image]

Also have dynamic values from G4 to G76 (updates every 5 mins).

I need to draw a border line across the entire row where value of G1 > G4:G76 (the range)

Since value in G42 is greater than G1 the border line is drawn across B42 to L42 however this border line will shift above or below based on value changes in G1

```vb
Sub Macro1()
    
Dim r As Range, r2 As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
    
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    With ws
        Set r = .Range("G1:G76" & .Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
        All_Borders_Off ws
        For Each r2 In r
            If r2.Value > G1 Then
                With r2.Offset(, -5).Resize(, 11)
                    .Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).Weight = xlThin
                    .BorderAround Weight:=xlThin
                End With
            End If
        Next
    End With
Next
End Sub


Sub All_Borders_Off(ws As Worksheet)
With ws.UsedRange
    .Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    .Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
    .Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlNone
    .Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlNone
    .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlNone
    .Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlNone
    .Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlNone
    .Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlNone
End With
End Sub
```

Code borders all rows irrespective of the Value > than G1 but this is what I need.
[image: This is how I need the Row Border to look like]

Comment: `.Range("G1:G76" & .Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)` should be `.Range("G1:G" & .Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)`. Then, it will be much faster to create a `Union Range` where to place all the matched ranges and apply borders at once, after the loop.

Comment: @FaneDuru even after changing (G76 to G) it puts borders in all the rows, did not help much, I only need it in one row thats greater than the G1 cell.

Comment: OK. I will post an answer...

Comment: @FaneDuru thx bro, I have exhausted all possibilities trying to use conditional formatting, but seems its a little more complicated than that and need to use macro for a solution

Comment: Please, test the answer I placed and send some feedback.

Comment: @FaneDuru Your change of CODE does half the job every other row greater than G1 value is bordered, the lesser value shows no border. if u take a look at the image every value greater than 18550 is bordered. I only need border at 18550 level, let me know if u need a screenshot

Comment: I am afraid I cannot get you... What do you understand from "I need to draw a border line across the entire row where value of G1 > G4:G76"? Shouldn't the code "draw a border for rows greater than G1 range value? In fact, I took the range to be bordered from your code and make the code placing the border around ranges having a value in  G:G column greater than the  one in G1. Isn't it what you want? If not, please better describe what you need. In words or using pictures (before and after processing, please).

Comment: Maybe i failed to get my point across to u, what i want is that only the nearest value row should be bordered not all the rows greater than G1, for eg if value in G1 is 18563 then the border line should be between18550 to 18600 since value in G1 is between these two, rest other rows should not be bordered at all. Can u see the attached image there happens to be only one border line between 18550 and 18600 values in G column

Comment: That interval is strange and I cannot understand the logic based on what to determine it.  18550 is less than 18563 and 18600 is greater than 18563. In your question you say something in words and something else in the code. I thought that the code matches better your need. Now I still do not understand what you want. Please, edit your question and place a picture **with borders around the values you want them bordered** and **better explain based on what logic they to be calculated**. I can see that the range is sorted. Do you want border arrownd a **specific area**? If so, based on what?.

Comment: Im trying a workaround with your peice of code, however I am getting "Compile error Sub or Function not defined in Line "All_Borders_Off" At first it was working now there seems to be some issue. Could u figure why?

Comment: How to "figure" anything without knowing what you try? Wouldn't it be simpler to **try explaining WHAT YOU NEED**?

Comment: I pasted the code as is in the Module window...no changes however I am getting a compile error, there are no other macros apart from this one.

Comment: What do you understand by "Module window"?  My solution uses **your `All_Borders_Off` sub**. If you deleted it, that should be the reason of the error. But if you cannot understand this simple aspect and you do not want clearly explaining what you need, I am afraid that I cannot help. If you are not able to help us understanding what you want, you cannot be helped. Have a nice evening!

Comment: Dear @FaneDuru Just commenting the line ['URange.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).Weight = xlThin] really did the job the line becomes dynamic based on value in G1, however it creates an entire border from B to L column where the border is made, anyway I'll try figuring something out but You have been kind & patient with me, I am not so good in programming so i could not get my issue across to you in a more precise manner, anyway good work here, can u guide how can i rate your answer.

Comment: If you consider that my code answered your question you should check the answer code left side check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. In this way, somebody else searching for a similar issue will know that the code works as it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would have `Option Explicit` on top of your module, you could see that `G1` is considered a variable (not declared...), being considered as `vbNullSTring`... Then, using a `Union Range`, as suggested in my comment, will considerably increase the code speed. Please use the next adapted code:

```
Sub MacroPlaceBorders()
  Dim r As Range, r2 As Range, URange As Range, ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    With ws
        Set r = .Range("G1:G" & .Range("G" & rows.count).End(xlUp).row)
        All_Borders_Off ws
        For Each r2 In r
            If r2.Value > ws.Range("G1").Value Then
               addToRange URange, r2.Offset(, -5).Resize(, 11)
            End If
        Next
    End With
    If Not URange Is Nothing Then
           'URange.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).Weight = xlThin
           URange.BorderAround Weight:=xlThin
           Set URange = Nothing 'preparing it for the next sheet
    End If
 Next
End Sub

Sub addToRange(rngU As Range, rng As Range)
    If rngU Is Nothing Then
        Set rngU = rng
    Else
        Set rngU = Union(rngU, rng)
    End If
End Sub
```

It uses your existing sub which deletes all existing border lines.